# Using Drupal Commerce, how do you render the "add to cart" button?

Tags: 7, forms, theming, commerce

I have created a custom node.tpl.php file for the product_display content type. I have everything worked out except I have no ideal how to isolate the "add to cart" button, actually the "add to cart" form, and render it within the template wherever I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product reference itself renders as the button. In your product display content type, make sure the product reference has the "Add to Cart form" format, then render it thus:

```
<?php print render($content['field_product']); ?>
```

Comment: I have seen this solution many many times, but mine just wont show anything, not even an error message and the format is set to "add to cart".

Comment: I got I!... I was trying to do all this in teaser mode so I had to modify the teaser display, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can add the "Add to Cart" button to your D7 taxonomy or front page view by visiting Structure -> Content Types -> [Product Type] / Manage Display -> Teaser.

Answer (score 1):

To add the "Add to cart" button, go to the manage display of the product reference field and set "Add to Cart form" in Format column.

Comment: I would expect this as default behaviour. Thanks for sharing.